# How to configure kubectl to connect to EKS using OIDC (Azure AD)?

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, kubectl, amazon-eks

I have configured Azure AD application as OIDC provider, associated OIDC in config EKS. Now I want to access using kubectl but I am not able to do using the following config.

ERROR : Unable to connect to the server: No valid id-token, and cannot refresh without refresh-token

```
kubectl config set-credentials aman \
   --auth-provider=oidc \
   --auth-provider-arg=idp-issuer-url=<my azure one> \
   --auth-provider-arg=client-id=<my client id> \
   --auth-provider-arg=client-secret=<my secret id>
```

whereas I can connect using oidc plugins for kubectl with the same details.
What am I doing wrong ?

I don't understand why it is asking refresh tokens. Plus I don't have refresh tokens.

NOTE: I followed EKS official doc to configure https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/authenticate-oidc-identity-provider.html and Kubernetes official doc to set kubectl https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#using-kubectl

Could anyone suggest anything where I don't need to use any oidc plugin with kubectl ?

Answer (score 1):

So, I have been doing some research and I think I found the answer. I am posting my findings so that it can help if someone struggles with the same question.

The way Kubernetes is authenticating with kubectl is with bearer_token. Now a bearer_token consists of access_token and refresh_token. But we can only have id token and here the oidc plugin comes to play. According to the Kubernetes official doc i.e. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/

`The first option is to use the kubectl oidc authenticator, which sets the id_token as a bearer token for all requests and refreshes the token once it expires.`

In other words since EKS is providing only authentication with OIDC, it needs only id_token. Then we need the help of oidc plugin which can set our id_token as bearer_token. Hence we don't need to provide any refresh token with oidc authenticator plugins.

P.S.

Authorization is later taken care by RBAC features. In my case I mapped my AD groups to Kubernetes groups with roles and role bindings.